# How can i check if listView items contains FileInfo variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[i]);
if (listView1.Items.Contains(fi.FullName))
```

The error is on:

```
listView1.Items.Contains(fi.FullName)
```

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'

And

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.Contains(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem)' has some invalid arguments

And in the bottom of my code i have this:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button5.Text == "Unselect All Items")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    listView1.SetSelected(i, false);
                }
                button5.Text = "Select All Items";
            }
            else
            {
                if (listView1.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        listView1.SetSelected(i, true);
                    }
                    button5.Text = "Unselect All Items";
                }
            }
        }
```

But listView1 dosen't have the property SetSelected before it i had listBox but now i'm using listView is there any way to get over it ?

Comment: You need to use a linq query here: listView1.Items.Where(x => x.Fullname == fi.FullName);  Change x.FullName to what ever property you want to compare. You can null check the return value or even do linq.ANy to return a bool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Any(item=>item.Text == fi.FullName))
{
   // whatever you want
}
```